# Why error ???? Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Sub register_user()
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\login.mdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim reg As New DataTable("loginadmin")
    Dim aaa As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from loginadmin ", con)
    Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Insert into loginadmin(username,password) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')", con)



    rs.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("user successfully registerd")

    con.Close()

End Sub
```

'debugger caught this error " syntax error insert into statement"
'the da

Comment: Did you check the generated query string in debugger? Also, you really should use parametrized queries.

Comment: password is a **[reserved word](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/248738)** and should be enclosed in square brackets. `[password]`

Comment: Please provide the full error message

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :-  Dim rs As New OleDb.OleDbCommand `("Insert into loginadmin([username],[password]) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "')", con)`